# We should use abbreviation full name with capital first letters in footnote?

Tags: articles, abbreviations, footnotes

Suppose that I have a abbreviation in a scientific article and using a footnote for full name. Which one is true?

```
Abbreviation (in text): AHS

Footnote1: American Healthcare Society
Footnote2 : American healthcare society
Footnote3 : american healthcare society
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same rules apply as for normal text: if it's a proper noun **all** the words should be capitalised, but otherwise none of them should be, unless the first word starts the sentence.

Thus, AHS[1] and MRI[2] (not a proper noun) would expand in footnotes to:

> 1. American Healthcare Society.
> 2. Magnetic resonance imaging.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Is software name is a plural name? For example `Virus Detection System (VDS)`? or `International Standard Industrial Classiﬁcation (ISIC)`?

Comment: @user2991243 Did you mean "Is software name a *proper noun*"? If so, then it depends whether you are referring to a specific software product (e.g. Internet Explorer), or a general type of software package (e.g. word processor).

Comment: @user2991243 International Standard Industrial Classiﬁcation is a proper noun.